# Exclusive OR (XOR) in vb6 versus c#

Tags: c#, vb6, xor

I am converting a vb6 program to c# and I cannot figure out why the results of my exclusive or operation are giving me different values.

The vb6 code:

```
'serialNum = 884167284, and dSize = 1953312760 here'
serialNum = serialNum Xor dSize       'serialNum = 1088322956 after this operation'
serialNum = serialNum Xor &HD7BF3A9C  'serialNum = -1755232496 after this operation'
GetDriveSerialNum = serialNum
```

The c# code:

```
//serialNum = 884167284, and dSize = 1953312760 here
serialNum = serialNum ^ dSize;       //serialNum = 1088322956 after this operation
serialNum = serialNum ^ 0xD7BF3A9C;  //serialNum = 2539734800 after this operation
return serialNum;
```

I need the c# code to give the negative number that is the result of the vb6 code. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: What are the data types of `serialNum` in both languages?

Comment: It's not the `xor`, it's the datatypes...

Comment: They are both long in both languages

Comment: Looks like you have a signed type in VB6 and an unsigned type in C#.

Comment: VB6 Long is 32-bit, C# Long is 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `long` in vb6 is a 32 bit signed value, so its range is - 2,147,483,468 to  2,147,483,468.

A `long` in C# is a 64 bit signed value, so its range is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

In the vb6 XOR you are overflowing, thus why the number is negative.  To get the same value, you can use an `int` in C#.

Comment: And to get the same result... use an *int* in C#.

Comment: Technically, this is not an overflow. The number is negative because the most significant bit is high as a result of the bit-wise XOR operation and the interpretation of the resulting image into a signed integer.

Answer (score 3):

C# `long` datatype is 64bit long signed integer. VB6 `long` datatype is 32bit signed integer. So in VB6 you are getting the sign bit of your operation set, while in C# it is unset.

Use a 32bit integer type in C# instead (`int` / `Int32`).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `long` data type in VB6 is a 32 bit signed integer and in C# it is a 64 bit signed integer you need to use the `uint` data type in C#.

```
        uint serialNum = 884167284;
        uint dSize = 1953312760;

        serialNum = serialNum ^ dSize;
        serialNum = serialNum ^ 0xD7BF3A9C;

        //Your signed representation -1755232496.
        int serialNumSigned = (int)serialNum;
```